# XML Parsing in DB2 - Multiple row generating expressions in single XML CLOB field

Tags: xml, parsing, db2, xmltable

My XML is having complex structure where there are multiple occurrences of repetitive nodes (multiple row generators).

**Query:**

```
select  X.*, A.id
from tbl_with_blob a,
XMLTABLE(
'$XMLDATA//BusData/LOB1/Vehicle' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
COLUMNS
--these columns are getting parsed correctly - since they are having only one node
"vehicle_id" varchar(50) PATH '@id'
,"manufacturer" varchar(100) PATH 'let $x := . return $x/Manufacturer/.'
,"loc_ref_id" varchar(100) PATH 'let $x := . return $x/@LocationRef'

--these columns are throwing error - because there are multiple nodes with the same name
,"x_vc1_1" varchar(1000) PATH 'let $x := . return $x/Vehicle_child1/Vehicle_child1_1/.'
,"x_SC1_1" varchar(1000) PATH 'let $x := . return $x/Vehicle_child1/SomeCode1_1/.'
,"x_Vc2_varcd" varchar(1000) PATH 'let $x := . return $x/Vehicle_child2/@varCd'
,"x_vc2_lmitamt" varchar(100) PATH 'let $x := . return $x/Vehicle_child2/Limit/FormatInteger/.'
) as X
where id='<some_id>'
with ur;
```

**XML:**

```
<BusData>
<LOB1>
<Vehicle id="A333" LocationRef="A194">
  <Manufacturer id="A306">TOYT<Manufacturer>
  
  <Vehicle_child1 id="A303">
    <Vehicle_child1_1 id="A400">RoadSideInd</Vehicle_child1_1>  
  </Vehicle_child1>
  
  <Vehicle_child1 id="A399">
    <Vehicle_child1_1 id="A407">Commercial</Vehicle_child1_1>
    <SomeCode1_1 id="A436">NO</SomeCode1_1>
  </Vehicle_child1>
  
  <Vehicle_child1 id="A434">  
  <Vehicle_child1_1 id="A412">VehAgreedValue</Vehicle_child1_1>
    <SomeCode1_1 id="A474"/>
    <Num id="A476">1000</Num>
  </Vehicle_child1>
  
  <Vehicle_child2 id="A411" varCd="47" varSomeLimit="500">
    <Vehicle_child2Cd id="A412">COLL</Vehicle_child2Cd> 
  </Vehicle_child2>
  
  <Vehicle_child2 id="A413" varCd="08" varSomeLimit="300">
    <Vehicle_child2Cd id="A501">UMCSL</Vehicle_child2Cd>    
    <SomeLimit id="A498">
      <FormatInteger id="A499">30000<FormatInteger>
    </SomeLimit>
  </Vehicle_child2>
  
  <Vehicle_child2 id="A503" varCd="0A" varSomeLimit="450">
    <Vehicle_child2Cd id="A517">CLMFG</Vehicle_child2Cd>    
    <SomeLimit id="A521">
      <FormatInteger id="A532">6000<FormatInteger>
    </SomeLimit>
  </Vehicle_child2>
  
<Vehicle>
</LOB1>
</BusData>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id        vehicle_id    manufacturer    loc_ref_id  x_vc1_1     x_SC1_1  x_Vc2_varcd      x_vc2_lmitamt
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        RoadSideInd (null)   47               (null)
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        RoadSideInd (null)   08               30000
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        RoadSideInd (null)   0A               6000
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        Commercial  NO       47               (null)
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        Commercial  NO       08               30000
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        Commercial  NO       0A               6000
HT56NU4M    A333        TOYT            A194        VehValue    (null)   47               (null)
HT56NU4M    N333        TOYT            A194        VehValue    (null)   08               30000
HT56NU4M    N333        TOYT            A194        VehValue    (null)   0A               6000
```

When I use the above query - I get the below error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE= -16003, SQLSTATE=10507,SQLERRMC=(item(), item()+);item(), DRIVER=4.23.42
```

I tried to modify the *row-generating expression* to include one of the row generators as *Vehicle_child1*, where it gave correct results for *Vehicle_child1*, but *Vehicle_child2* was missing.

I need to have both(in real time it can be as many as 10 or 15) the row generators combined and giving multiple rows for each occurrence .

Could anybody please help me - how to use multiple row-generating expressions in XMLTABLE function in DB2 ?

Thanks
LN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH tbl_with_blob (ID, XML_COL_TEXT) AS 
(
VALUES
('HT56NU4M', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<BusData>
<LOB1>
  <Vehicle id="A333" LocationRef="A194">
  <Manufacturer id="A306">TOYT</Manufacturer>
  
  <Vehicle_child1 id="A303">
    <Vehicle_child1_1 id="A400">RoadSideInd</Vehicle_child1_1>  
  </Vehicle_child1>
  
  <Vehicle_child1 id="A399">
    <Vehicle_child1_1 id="A407">Commercial</Vehicle_child1_1>
    <SomeCode1_1 id="A436">NO</SomeCode1_1>
  </Vehicle_child1>
  
  <Vehicle_child1 id="A434">  
    <Vehicle_child1_1 id="A412">VehAgreedValue</Vehicle_child1_1>
    <SomeCode1_1 id="A474"/>
    <Num id="A476">1000</Num>
  </Vehicle_child1>
  
  <Vehicle_child2 id="A411" varCd="47" varSomeLimit="500">
    <Vehicle_child2Cd id="A412">COLL</Vehicle_child2Cd> 
  </Vehicle_child2>
  
  <Vehicle_child2 id="A413" varCd="08" varSomeLimit="300">
    <Vehicle_child2Cd id="A501">UMCSL</Vehicle_child2Cd>    
    <SomeLimit id="A498">
      <FormatInteger id="A499">30000</FormatInteger>
    </SomeLimit>
  </Vehicle_child2>
  
  <Vehicle_child2 id="A503" varCd="0A" varSomeLimit="450">
    <Vehicle_child2Cd id="A517">CLMFG</Vehicle_child2Cd>    
    <SomeLimit id="A521">
      <FormatInteger id="A532">6000</FormatInteger>
    </SomeLimit>
  </Vehicle_child2>
  
</Vehicle>
</LOB1>
</BusData>'))
)
*/
select A.id, X1.*, X2.*
from 
  tbl_with_blob a
, XMLTABLE
(
'$XMLDATA/BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/Vehicle_child1' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
COLUMNS
  "vehicle_id"   varchar(50)   PATH '@id'
, "manufacturer" varchar(100)  PATH '../Manufacturer'
, "loc_ref_id"   varchar(100)  PATH '../@LocationRef'
, "x_vc1_1"      varchar(1000) PATH 'Vehicle_child1_1'
, "x_SC1_1"      varchar(1000) PATH 'SomeCode1_1'
) X1
, XMLTABLE
(
'$XMLDATA/BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/Vehicle_child2' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
COLUMNS
 "x_Vc2_varcd"   varchar(1000) PATH '@varCd'
,"x_vc2_lmitamt" varchar(100)  PATH 'SomeLimit/FormatInteger'
) X2;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mark !! That worked like a charm !!! But I have a quick question - When I have multiple XML records - this will do a cross product on each of those records - correct ?

Comment: No, you get cross join inside a single document only as in this example. 3 *_child1 X 3 *_child2 = 9 records from 1 xml document. Records from different documents are not crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mark - I used your approach to write a query something like this:

```
with sub_x1 as 
( 
 select 
    A.id, X1.*
 from tbl_with_blob a,
 XMLTABLE('$XMLDATA//BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/Vehicle_child1' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
 COLUMNS
 "vehicle_id" varchar(50) PATH '@id'
  -- and other cols --
  ) as X1
where id='<some_id>'
),
sub_x2 as 
( 
 select 
    A.id, X2.*
 from tbl_with_blob a,
 XMLTABLE('$XMLDATA//BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/Vehicle_child2' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
 COLUMNS
 "some_code1" varchar(50) PATH '@id'
  -- and other cols --
  ) as X1
where id='<some_id>'
),

sub_x3 as 
( 
 select 
    A.id, X3.*
 from tbl_with_blob a,
 XMLTABLE('$XMLDATA//BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/some_other_node/s_o_n/some_child1' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
 COLUMNS
 "some_other_cd" varchar(50) PATH '@id'
  -- and other cols --
  ) as X3
where id='<some_id>'
),

sub_x4 as 
( 
 select 
    A.id, X4.*
 from tbl_with_blob a,
 XMLTABLE('$XMLDATA//BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/yet_other_node/y_a_c_n/yet_another_child2' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
 COLUMNS
 "yet_other_cd" varchar(50) PATH '@id'
  -- and other cols --
  ) as X4
where id='<some_id>'
),
sub_x5 as 
( 
 select 
    A.id, X5.*
 from tbl_with_blob a,
 XMLTABLE('$XMLDATA//BusData/LOB1/Vehicle/yet_other_node/y_o_n/yet_another_child2' passing XML_COL_TEXT as "XMLDATA"
 COLUMNS
 "yet_other_cd2" varchar(50) PATH '@id'
  -- and other cols --
  ) as X5
where id='<some_id>'
)
select 
 X1.<cols>,
 X2.<cols>,
 X3.<cols>,
 X4.<cols>,
 X5.<cols>,
from X1, X2, X3, X4, X5
where 
X1.id=X2.id
and (X1.id=X3.id and X2.id=X3.id)
and (X1.id=X4.id and X2.id=X4.id and X3.id=X4.id)
and (X1.id=X5.id and X2.id=X5.id and X3.id=X5.id and X4.id=X5.id)

with ur;
```

This continues to run and each individual query gives correct set of results and unique rows. X1 gives 4 rows, X2 gives 9, X3 gives 11, X4 gives 7 and X5 gives 6.
Each of these sub queries contains XML XPaths which are recurring within their immediate parent nodes - a number of times.

But as a whole query gives a cross product of these - 16632 rows.
Obviously I am missing something here in the JOIN conditions ?

Thanks
LNC

Comment: No. My query is intended to be used with a table of (id, xml, ...) structure namely as described. WITH clause is used just to form the table contents on the fly. You should use your real `tbl_with_blob` without this clause. You may add another "row" to my "virtual" table inside `WITH` in the form of `VALUES ('ID1', XMLPARSE(...)), ('ID2', XMLPARSE(...))` and check what happens. Don't do any other changes to my example.

Comment: Sure Mark. Will check tomorrow and let you know. Thanks very much for your support. :)

Comment: I tried using ```WITH .. VALUES ... ``` but it seems like the version of DB2 which I am using is not supporting this feature.

Comment: What is your db2 version and platform?